# How do I change the color or size of the code suggestion dots that show up under VS Code hints?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code with the C# dev kit. When I write some code that is not a compile error, but could be improved, there will be three red dots the show up under my code. They are sort of hard for me to see.

Is there a way I can either make these dots bigger, or a different color? I already use my own custom theme, but I have no clue what is controlling the color of these dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the colour using the `editorHint.foreground` colour customization point. Ex. in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorHint.foreground": "#ff0000"
},
```

I don't think there's a way to change the size. You could [raise a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).